# Cordova app is running smoothest when I touch screen and don't leave finger

Tags: android, cordova, cocos2d-x

Recently I created a Cordova app for my html5 game created in Cocos Creator engine.
After some time, I noticed the app running on android not as smooth as in browser. I googled a lot of questions but all they said problem is Cordova using some default Web View what have bad performance. I tried a lot of solutions, but no one helped me.

Today I noticed, when I run my app, touch screen and don't leave my finger, the app starts to run very smoothly (as in browser). I am wondering what is the reason of such behaviour?
Maybe there is some acceleration what start to run only when I touch the screen?

Also, any advices how I can fix lagging in Cordova android build are welcomed.

Solutions I tried:

Plugins:
ionic-webview,
crosswark-webview

setting

> android:hardwareAccelerated
>
> true/false

in the manifest

Some other small solutions from internet, I currently can't remember. No One of this helped my. Only when I touch the screen I see performance boost.

This issue occurs only on my new phone (was bought in 2020),
in the old one (2017) app runs smoothly without touch.

Thanks!

UPDATE
Cordova version is 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
Platform android version is 9.1.0

config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-packageName="com.android.m" android-versionCode="6" id="com.android.m" version="1.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>My game</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />
        <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
        <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: @Eric added in the question

Comment: Why not use latest version of cordova-android ?

Comment: @Eric Added latest version of cordova-android: 10.1.1. Haven't any effect.

Comment: Are you using iconic? This isn't clear. Please paste plugins you use.

Comment: @Eric no, I am not using ionic. As I said, I tried ionic-webview plugin, but it doesn't help.

Comment: At this point, it might be code related or even related to cocos, since it is related to a touch event... Hard to tell without code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239793/discussion-between-yurii-horchynskyi-and-eric).

Comment: @Eric Thanks for reply. I am not sure it related to cocos. I Have removed all scripts/canvas related to cocos, created single html box and move it by changing css "left" property. Behaviour the same. FPS meter shows me 60 fps, but refresh rate on the screen looks like 30 FPS. When  touch the screen, box starts to move more smoothly.

Comment: @Eric Also I noticed it runs ok in my old one phone (was bought in 2017), but in new one (2020) I have issue I explained.

Comment: Then it's proper to your new phone I'm afraid